# Delete index in list if multiple strings are matched

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I've scraped a website containing a table and I want to format the headers for my desired final out.

```
headers = []

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for item in row.findAll('th'):
        for link in item.findAll('a', text=True):
            headers.append(link.contents[0])

print headers
```

Which returns:

```
[u'Rank ', u'University Name ', u'Entry Standards', u'Click here to read more', u'Student Satisfaction', u'Click here to read more', u'Research Quality', u'Click here to read more', u'Graduate Prospects', u'Click here to read more', u'Overall Score', u'Click here to read more', u'\r\n            2016\r\n        ']
```

I don't want the "Click here to read more' or '2016' headers so I've done the following:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(headers):
    if 'Click' in i:
        del headers[idx]
for idx, i in enumerate(headers):
    if '2016' in i:
        del headers[idx]
```

Which returns:

```
[u'Rank ', u'University Name ', u'Entry Standards', u'Student Satisfaction', u'Research Quality', u'Graduate Prospects', u'Overall Score']
```

Perfect. But is there a better/neater way of removing the unwanted items? Thanks!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to remove elements from a sequence you are currently iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using list comprehension to get a new, filtered list, something like:

```
new_headers = [header for header in headers if '2016' not in header]
```

Comment: @datasci It was just a suggestion for the OP. There's no problem to change my suggestion to `new_headers = [header for header in headers if '2016' not in header and 'Click' not in header]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
headers = filter(lambda h: not 'Click' in h and not '2016' in h, headers)
```

If you want to be more generic:

```
banned = ['Click', '2016']
headers = filter(lambda h: not any(b in h for b in banned), headers)
```

Comment: List comprehensions are preferred over `filter`

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = '^Click|^2016'

new = [x for x in header if not re.match(pattern,str(x).strip())]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that `'2016'` will always be last:

```
>>> [x for x in headers[:-1] if 'Click here' not in x]
['Rank ', 'University Name ', 'Entry Standards', 'Student Satisfaction', 'Research Quality', 'Graduate Prospects', 'Overall Score']
```